# printing čžšđć in command prompt with python

Tags: command-prompt, python-3.5

I am really frustrated:

I get an error when running python example.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
#it's python 3.5 anyway

epic = 'ščđžć'
print(epic)
```

I get:

```
return codec.charmap_encode(input,self.errors, encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'Charmap'
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run this command on windows which will change the format to UTF-8

```
chcp 65001
```